# can't connect to ssh in a Raspberry py with two network interfaces

Tags: raspbian, networking

I've looking a lot but I dont find the solution.

My Rpy has a 3G modem connected wich is the ppp0 interface and the wlan0 interfaces, both have internet access but **if I put the ppp0 with higer metric than wlan0 I can't connect via ssh to that interface**.

With this configuration I can connect via ssh to both internet interfaces.

**This Work**

```
default dev ppp0 scope link metric 10 
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.11.142 metric 304 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 186.191.19.110 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0 scope link src 169.254.139.160 metric 209 
192.168.11.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.11.142 metric 304 
192.168.40.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.40.100 metric 202
```

Only changing the metric from 10 to 500, and I cant conect via SSH to ppp0

**This dont work**

```
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.11.142 metric 304 
default dev ppp0 scope link metric 500 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 186.191.19.110 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0 scope link src 169.254.139.160 metric 209 
192.168.11.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.11.142 metric 304 
192.168.40.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.40.100 metric 202
```

Removing ppp0 from default interfaces also dont work.

What im trying to do is that wlan0 is used more to connect to internet but I need to connect via SSH in both interfaces.

Comment: I see no configuration.

Comment: I didn't change any configuration, the wlan0 interface is added by wpa service, wwan0 is added by dhcpcd when the modem is conected and the ppp0 is added by wvdial or pppd.
I only add manualy the default "dev ppp0 scope link metric 10 " to ip route to work.

If you need some config file, I can add it to the post

Comment: You can't have two `default` routes. Pick the one that will carry traffic outside your LAN.